# How to make installer which launches installer of another component if user selects it in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, windows-installer, desktop-application

I have made a desktop application in C++ (using QT) and now I want to make an installer of it and the application needs SQlShell to be installed in C:\Program Files to run.

So, My SqlShell should be installed

I want my installer to launch SQLShell installer if user selects it
But I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Please don't dump random files in the Windows installation directory. Ship your DLLs with your application instead.

Comment: Actually I don't know how to do this. I'm using SQL in c++ and it searches for LibmySql.dll in Windows directory that's why I need to do this

Answer (score 0):

you should first create an **exe file from your app** .
for doing this you should build your project in **release** mode.
then put the **app.exe** file and put it in another folder.
if your app has a database you should put the database file near your exe file and then use for example MinGW terminal and type `windeployqt app.exe`

For more details see these 2 videos on youtube :

1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LdSTgR0xJco
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hCXAgB6y8eA

Comment: Oh thanks bro it worked, I pasted libmysql.dll in my exe file and followed the steps in video and it worked

Comment: Bro can you tell me about this
I want my installer to launch SQLShell installer if user selects it But I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Well, I don't know this too.